# Jboss EAP download deployed war file

Tags: jboss, web-deployment, jboss-eap-6

I have deployed a war file through management console of JBOSS EAP to my company server. I lost my source code accidentally deleted. How can i download the file that's now running on the server to my local machine. Please help me

Comment: Looking for this on Google I found this solution, pretty easy if you have access to JBoss console, hope it helps if anyone finds it: https://www.dbappweb.com/2019/02/07/how-to-save-download-an-application-deployed-in-jboss-eap-7-1-content-repository/

Answer (score 1):

In the management console of JBoss, go to "Deployments", click the applicable deployment, click "View". Then you have the possibility to browse through all files in the war. Downloading the full war means clicking the war, and on the right, click "Download".

(all based on the 3.0.19.Final console version)

Answer (score 0):

When you have access to JBoss directory and you pack source code into jars so:
You deploy a war file through the management console your archive is saved on path:

```
JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment (in case when you are in standalone mode)
```

There you can see unpacked war file with jars. But java source code is usually converted to bitecode and you can not get code from it. Maybe you compose your jar with source code and you can see source code.

But unfortunately I don't know way how to do it through Management console.